# windows 10 pivot item text

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to change the default text style (foreground color, font weight, etc) for pivot item header text when the header is selected.

E.g., if I have the following:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="One"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Two"></PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

I want the selected pivot item to be bolded when selected and/or change the foreground color (or maybe put the text in a border, etc). I don't want to change the default style for the unselected items.

Thanx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The XAML framework offers many ways to customize the appearance of your apps. Styles let you set control properties and reuse those settings for a consistent appearance across multiple controls. You create a control template when you want to customize a control's visual structure and visual behavior.

You don't need to put the text of pivot header in a border, edit the [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.aspx) for `PivotHeaderItem` would be a good choice, and you can add this style to the [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187273.aspx) of the Page.

> Resources are typically definitions of some object that you expect to use more than once.

There is a default [PivotHeaderItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx), you can copy it and add this to you page resources just like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="..."
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
             ...
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now if you want to change the foreground of the text in header when the item is selected, you can edit the `<VisualState x:Name="Selected">` like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

If you want to change the text of header to be bold, you can edit above `VisualState` like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontWeight">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Bold" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

You can leave other `VisualState`s as defalut, if you just want to change the style when the item is selected.

Comment: That reminded me of something I came across awhile back. The various styles are defined on my system in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic in a file called generic.xml. I searched that file, found the style definition for PivotHeaderItem and copied that via the sample here. I added the font weight modifier and voila! Like a charm, it worked. Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

### In XAML

```
 <Pivot SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="One"></TextBlock>
            </PivotItem.Header>
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Two"></TextBlock>
            </PivotItem.Header>
        </PivotItem>
 </Pivot>
```

### In C#

```
 private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pivot pivot = sender as Pivot;
        PivotItem pivotItemSelected = ((PivotItem) ((Pivot) sender).SelectedItem);


        for (int i = 0; i < pivot.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            PivotItem pivotItem = pivot.Items[i] as PivotItem;
            TextBlock tb = pivotItem.Header as TextBlock;
            if (pivotItem == pivotItemSelected)
            {
                //Style 
                tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this can help you